# Plotly.js: How to change 'hovertemplate' in the box type

Tags: boxplot, plotly.js

I want to change the tooltip when hover the graph.
I don't want to display q1, q3.
Please help me on how to change my properties.

[image]

````
{type: "box", 
y: wear_out["data"], 
boxpoints:false, name:key,  
marker: {color: colors[4]},  
showlegend: false, 
hoverinfo:'text',
hovertemplate:'MAX:: %{y.max}<br> Min:: %{y.min}'} ```
````